# Dynamic Queries - Expando/Dynamic object type

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework-4.1

I need to query tables neither known or existing at compile time, publish the table via odata and then make it available to a silverlight client for CRUD.

Would be wonderful to use a PCO of type dynamic or ExpandoObject to acheive this but that doesn't seem to work (as suspected).

I'm wondering if there are Interfaces that would allow me to perform the type mapping and serializing at the row level so I would dynamically take the data row and round trip it's values on the server side.  Perhaps an interface for the PCO to "help", or dynmically created property getter/setter.  I'm also toying with dynamically creating the context class at run time but that's kind of ugly.

Then - on the client side, something to do the same thing with the odata feed,  I have a solution here but it aint pretty enough to share with the world.

Answer (score 0):

EF doesn't offer any "dynamic" approach as well as any simple way to let you create a new table and add it to mapping. Another question is how well can WCF Data Services work with changing data - I believe it is not supported as well.

If you want dynamically changed structure (added tables, columns etc.) use some metadata model instead of creating new table for each entity. Metadata model usually have something like table with common properties and related table with key value pair of attribute name and value. It can be futher extended to more complex scenarios but it is the only way how to achieve this. Instead of mapping in EF take your entity types as data.